# D3.js v4 - set padding for bar chart

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to add padding to my bar chart in D3.js v4.

In v3, it was done in the following way:

```
var x = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["a", "b", "c"])
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1);
```

However, in v4, `rangeRoundBands` was eliminated. I know that the equivalent code in v4 (without padding) is:

```
var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(["a", "b", "c"])
    .range([0, width]);
```

According to [this](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#scales-d3-scale), we should use `band.padding` to set the padding. So I tried this:

```
var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(["a", "b", "c"])
    .range([0, width])
    .padding(0.1);
```

But that doesn't seem to make an impact. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In D3 V4.

This is how you define the axis:

```
var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, width])
    .round(true)
    .padding(.1);//set padding like this
//set the domain like this
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));

//define the X axis like this

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(x);
```

working bar chart d3 v4 sample [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dbi0da0XIWFnZfcY7eHU?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! I think the key is to set `round(true)`, which is what was missing from my code.

Comment: Thanks this was clutch for me as well.